# Error when trying to install caffe on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, deep-learning, caffe, ubuntu-16.04

When i run the `make all` command, I get this error thrown at me after about 1-2 minutes:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:566: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it ? I have installed hdf5.

Comment: Have you tried the steps proposed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4333)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you still searching for it or no, but I got the similar problem and can fix it with help from this discussion.
[BVLC/caffe issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2347).
So basically you have to run this script:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's^"hdf5.h"^"hdf5/serial/hdf5.h"^g' -e 's^"hdf5_hl.h"^"hdf5/serial/hdf5_hl.h"^g' '{}' \;
```

then, change the makefile like below

```
--- LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf boost_system boost_filesystem m hdf5_hl hdf5
+++ LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf boost_system boost_filesystem m hdf5_serial_hl hdf5_serial
```

I hope it helps :)